# Upload Image failling with Message : Parameter is not valid even inside using - Tried many solutions created here in SO

Tags: c#, .net, image

I'm facing an issue that I cannot save an image after uploading it.

I tried many questions created here in SO, but none of then suits me and I can't fix.

When I try to resize this image and then saving it, I got this error message:

> Message:Parameter is not valid.StackTrace: at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format) at BLL.AuxiliarImagemBLL.ResizeImageUpload(Image img, Int32 left, Int32 top, Int32 width, Int32 height) at BLL.AuxiliarImagemBLL.UploadImgDestaque(HttpPostedFileBase File, Int32 WidthLimite, Int32 HeightLimite, String PathFisicoUploadArea)Data:System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternalUrl:System.Drawing

Even trying many answers that always saying **run out of memory**, I still cannot resolve this problem.

The line `newimage.Save(filepath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);` triggered the error.

Bellow my script that I try to resize and then save this image:

```
    public string UploadImgDestaque(HttpPostedFileBase File, int WidthLimite, int HeightLimite, string PathFisicoUploadArea)
    {
        string filepath = "";
        string filename = "";

        AuxiliarImagemBLL auxiliarImagemBLL = new AuxiliarImagemBLL();
        //Converte o arquivo em Imagem
        Image image = Image.FromStream(File.InputStream, true, true);
        Image newimage;

        try
        {
            if(File != null)
            {
                int WidthFinal = 0;
                int HeightFinal = 0;
                int left = 0;
                int top = 0;

                if(image.Width > WidthLimite)
                {
                    WidthFinal = WidthLimite;
                    double porcentagem = 1 - (Convert.ToDouble(WidthLimite) / Convert.ToDouble(image.Width));
                    HeightFinal = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(image.Height - (image.Height * porcentagem)));
                }
                else if(image.Width < WidthLimite)
                {
                    left = 0;
                    top = 0;
                    HeightFinal = image.Height;
                    WidthFinal = image.Width;
                }

                newimage = auxiliarImagemBLL.ResizeImageUpload(image, left, top, WidthFinal, HeightFinal);

                filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";
                filepath = PathFisicoUploadArea + filename;
                newimage.Save(filepath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);  //Error triggered here
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            int cniid = auxiliarCookieBLL.GetCNIId();
            AuxiliarBLL auxiliarBLL = new AuxiliarBLL();
            AppSettings appSubject_Error = new AppSettings(cniid, "SUBJECT_ERROR");
            auxiliarBLL.SendMailError(appSubject_Error.Value, "AuxiliarImagemBLL", "UploadImgDestaque", ex, cniid, "");
        }

        return filename;
    }
```

**ResizeImageUpload method:**

```
    public Image ResizeImageUpload(Image img, int left = 0, int top = 0, int width = 0, int height = 0)
    {
        using (var NovaImagem = new Bitmap(width, height))
        {
            //Bitmap NovaImagem = new Bitmap(width, height);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(NovaImagem))
            {
                g.Clear(Color.White);
                g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                g.DrawImage(img, left, top, width, height);
            }

            return (Image)NovaImagem;
        }
    }
```

Please, is there any other way that I can fix this issue and save the Image?
I put a comment in front of the line which this error happened.
If I need to put more information, please advise me.

Comment: Have you tried WebImage.Resize() class? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage.resize(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: And 'bode' type? you learn about the difference?

Comment: Yes, I've tried both of solution ('bode' type?) and didn't work.